# movie or slideshow creator with Javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, css, open-source

I'm looking for an open source JS tool that enables the user to create an animation on a set of slides and play this animation as a movie with specific time frames.

Answer (score 1):

"Javascript MotionJPEG/AVI Builder" works pretty well with Firefox. But it seems they are issues with Google Chrome and IE. I think you could also built a Java or a python extension and send the slides via AJAX. But that is a lot of work :p

http://ushiroad.com/mjpeg/

Comment: Is there a solution to this problem today? The above script does not work anymore as the Blobs have changed.